# Bulk load data issue in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, bulk-load

I want to bulk load the data into snowflake warehouse using pandas. Please find whole requirement below:

1. I have source data in snowflake table. I am reading the same in a dataframe.
2. After loading the data in dataframe, I have made changes in data using some pandas functions.
3. After these changes i need to load the data in snowflake again.

file size : 200k records

Things i have tried:

1. first created the for loop which was creating the insert statement at go and also loading the same. This script ran for ~4 hours and loaded ~9k records(so this is not a viable option).
2. Then i created the whole insert query earlier before executing it on database. This approach is also failing and taking a lot of time(same as the above one).
3. I tried parallel processing and also created batch for data. Still no luck.
4. Later i tried copy into approach and it is working.

But i do not want to use COPY into as it is only snowflake specific.

Please help me with bulk loading of data using python.

Comment: Hi - if you want to bulk load data into Snowflake why do you not want to use a technique that is specific to Snowflake? For option 2, why/how is it failing? If you don't want to use the functionality specifically provided to enable high performance bulk loading (COPY INTO) then it's not obvious what help you are expecting anyone to provide - inserting individual records is always going to be comparatively slow

Answer (score 0):

Try using the snowflake-connector-python library

```
import snowflake.connector

# Create a connection
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='<your_username>',
    password='<your_password>',
    account='<your_account_url>',
    warehouse='<your_warehouse>',
    database='<your_database>',
    schema='<your_schema>'
)
```

Snowflake provides the copy_into method to efficiently bulk load data. You can use it as follows:

```
import snowflake.connector.pandas_tools as sfpd

# Assuming you have a DataFrame called 'df' with your data
sfpd.write_pandas(conn, df, '<snowflake_table_name>')
```

This approach uses the built-in capabilities of Snowflake Connector for bulk loading, which should be much faster than inserting rows one at a time.

Comment: i have switched to Pyspark and same job is taking 15 mins now